# Sending data from `BraodcastReceiver` to `Activity`

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a MainActivity and a MyBroadcastReceiver. The `BroadcastReceiver` waits for incoming SMSes and reads the sms and senderId, it should send this data to `MainActivity` in real time. I have tried to implement the BroadcastReceiver in the Activity itself but it launches the activity again.

```
    Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 public static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "SMSCOMING";
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            try {
                //Getting the data d
                    triggerFunc(d);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        this.registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, filter);
}

void triggerFunc(data d){
   //Do some stuff
}

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that we have two kind of broadcast receivers in Android:

- Standalone broadcast receivers (one of four main Android building blocks). This type of receivers must be registered in Android manifest file. These receivers will be run whenever their matching intents are received, no matter app's UI is running or not.
- In-Activity broadcast receivers. This kind of receivers don't need to be registered in Manifest file, you should instead register them at runtime. These receivers are only run when their enclosing activity is active and running.

So, if you would like your app to be able to catch all SMS messages, regardless of its UI status, you would need the former option. However if you would need your app to catch SMS message while its activity is shown, you would need the latter option.

Comment: Can you please some example or just provide a relevant link

Answer (score 0):

When the `BroadcastReceiver` receives an SMS notification, it cannot know if the `Activity` is running or not. If you want to launch the Activity, you need to create an appropriate `Intent` and call `Context.startActivity()`.

You should create a class which extends `BroadcastReceiver` rather than simply an instance of an anonymous inner class. Also, you should register your `BroadcastReceiver` using the [`<receiver>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I have been implementing the `BroadcastReceiver` in the Activity itself (like above mentioned) Please tell how to add this receiver in AndroidManifest as it is showing an error.

Comment: @shikharbansal I added a link to my answer for the details. I suggest you become familiar with the official Android documentation at http://d.android.com. This provides a good starting point for learning about anything in the Android API.

Answer (score 0):

***whatever code you have added in question as per that your `Receiver` only called when you `Activity` is running. instead of that create broadcast separately(remove from activity & create new class in your package) and register in `AndroidManifest` file and call your activity from Receiver.***

just like below.

create BroadcastReceiver Class in your package.

```
public class BinarySMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            try {
                //Getting the data d
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClassName(context, "activity.class");
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    context.startActivity(intent);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
```

in AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.company.application.SMSBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="500">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: You fixed it in an edit while I was typing my comment.

Comment: won't the `context.startActivity` will launch a new Instance of the same Activity.

Comment: create broadcast separately(remove from activity) and register in AndroidManifest file and call your activity from Receiver.

Comment: I created the broadcast separately and registered in the AndroidManifest file. I do not want to call the activity from the receiver. The activity is already running. The data that receiver sends should be updated on the activity screen.